# Permit standard users to add and remove printers

Tags: centos, cups, polkit

I'm trying to allow non-root users to add printers via the desktop GUI on CentOS 7 without being prompted for a password. I've attempted setting up both a custom Polkit rule and modifying the CUPS configuration, but haven't had any success.

Printer addition is completely blocked via the GUI, even for root users. The only way to add printers is through the terminal using sudo commands.

Here's what I have tried:

- Custom Polkit rule targeting "org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-device" and "org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units" actions for users in the lp group.
- Modified /etc/cups/cups-files.conf by adding lp to the SystemGroup definition.

Polkit rule (/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/51-custom-printer.rules)

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
  if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-device" &&
    subject.isInGroup("lp")) {
    return polkit.Result.YES;
  }
});

polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
  if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units" &&
    action.lookup("unit") == "cups.service" &&
    subject.isInGroup("lp")) {
    return polkit.Result.YES;
  }
});
```

CUPS configuration (`/etc/cups/cups-files.conf`)

```
# Administrator user group, used to match @SYSTEM in cupsd.conf policy rules...
SystemGroup sys root lp
```